# Prove $\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^x \left(\sin \pi t\right)^2\left[\frac{1}{(t-a)^2}+\frac{1}{(t+a)^2}\right]dt\geq \frac{x-a}{1+x-a}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Prove that
$$\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^x \left(\sin \pi t\right)^2\left[\frac{1}{(t-a)^2}+\frac{1}{(t+a)^2}\right]dt\geq \frac{x-a}{1+x-a}$$
for every $x\geq a>0$. I do not know where to start! Any suggestions please?

Comment: i think maybe you can put $f(t)=\frac{1}{(t-a)^2}+\frac{1}{(t+a)^2}$ , $g(t)=sin(\pi t)$ and use second mean value theorem for integration https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: @Mann, thank you but your instruction is wrong; the correct statement is: integrate (sin (pi t))^2 [1/(t-a)^2+1/(t+a)^2] dt from 0<t<x

Comment: Uhmm yes, i have thought of one idea to try solve it, Define $f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^x \left(\sin \pi t\right)^2\left[\frac{1}{(t-a)^2}+\frac{1}{(t+a)^2}\right]dt - \frac{x-a}{1+x-a}$ , 

Then you'd have to prove that this is $f(x)>0  \forall x\geq a$ , i.e try take derivative.